# Android SDK path on Mac missing

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

Currently running Android Studio 2.1.2 on Mac OS X El Capitan. I'm trying to locate the path of the Android SDK; when I go to File -> Project Structure to check the Android SDK location, I get the following:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

However, I can't find this folder on my system, there's no 'Library' folder under my user directory? I also tried showing hidden files but that didn't help. 
I'm pretty new to Android development so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Library is a hidden folder. If you open Finder and click the Go menu and hold the Option key you'll see it there.

Answer (score 9):

### **DON'T PANIC**

You can find it by doing some simple steps.
 In the beginning you have to make hidden files visible on your Mac(because SDK folder located in another folder which is hidden) to do this, you have to open [Terminal](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-use-terminal-on-mac-3608274/) and simply copy and paste this line in there and press Enter:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Like this picture:

[image: How to insert this line in Terminal]

We use this to make your hidden files visible. Don't worry!!! you can **UNDO** this just by writing "**NO**" instead of "**YES**"

Ok we almost there! keep up the good job  This step is about to finding the **SDK folder** and is not difficult! The Library folder located in the current user directory, like this picture:

[image]

**Sometimes Library folder stays still hidden or hidden files remains permanently visible, so use these keys together to make them hidden or visible:**

`SHIFT` + `CMD` + `.`

Then you will see the windows refreshed and you see the Library folder like so:

[image]

**Hope you find this useful, otherwise just ask your question in the comments :)**

Comment: This should be top comment. The top one doesn't cover edge cases where you need to select a folder from more than one context.

Answer (score 0):

Library folder is **hidden**

**Unhide** it by press `Command`+`Shift`+ command.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

did not work for me.

Solution:
Finder(open Finder)->Go(select Go menu)->Home
Right click on free place -> Show view options -> Show Library Folder (on my Sierra 10.12 it is the last checkbox) select.

That's all: Library folder becomes regular folder (according to look) and accessible from other applications (in my case from Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, I tried this in Mac OS X El Captian 10.11.6

1. In the Finder, choose to Go > Go to Folder
2. In the Go To Folder dialog box, type `~/Library`
3. Click Go.