# Android Studio 4.1.1 won't launch on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, macos-big-sur

I had an outdated Android Studio app and after updating to the latest version the app won't launch.

Clicking on opening the app shows the launch screen and after that saying "No android SDK found", pressing next and continue to update shows "Nothing to do, SDK is up to date", after that - nothing.

Tried:

- remove completely Android Studio and all files using terminal commands
- Uninstall and reinstall android studio from scratch

No window, nothing. Only the Android studio button on the status bar and that's it. I can't even close the app without a force quit.

What shows on the status bar after the finish:
[image: The status bar]

The only message on launch (after clicking next shows "nothing to do, sdk is up to date"):
[image: Missing SDK]

After that, just nothing, no window, seeing my Desktop and that's all.

Comment: You have to set SDK path. see this :  [Missing SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905253/android-sdk-path-on-mac-missing)

Comment: I checked the Library folder and there is SDK there.
Also, I can't set anything because the whole Android Studio platform not even working.
The only version that works is 3.6.1 above that nothing.

Comment: Same issue , any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but solved it by deleting configuration files from previous Android Studio installations as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues)
(Section: Studio doesn't start after upgrade).

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Apparently it clears out any cached settings, and launches A.S. from fresh install.

Answer (score -1):

I did a fresh install of Big Sur yesterday on my Catalina machine. Today I updated my Android Studio 3.5.3 installation there to latest Android 4.1.1 and had no issues with running and building with Android Studio 4.1.1 for my Android native and React Native apps.